# jQuery Add Input Option Class if Option Value in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to add a class to select option value based on array values received from ajax call.

**HTML**

```
<select id="my_id">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//array received from ajax call 
var array = [1,3,5]

// loop through dropdown options 
$("#my_id > option").each(function(i) {

    // if option value in array, add class 
    if ( array.indexOf(i.value) != -1 ) {

        // set matching values to red color 
        $(this).addClass("red");
    }

});
```

Comment: Just a typo. I do have different values in there so I just quickly typed this small sample. Good eye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the callback is the index being iterated over, not the element. To get to element, reference `this`, so that `this.value` gets you to the value you want to examine.

But the `.value` of an element will always be a string, so turn the array of numbers into an array of strings as well.

You can also consider using `.includes` instead of an `indexOf` check, it's more appropriate when just checking to see if an array includes a value (and is a bit more readable):

```js
//array received from ajax call 
var array = [1, 3, 5]
const arrayStrs = array.map(String);

// loop through dropdown options 
$("#my_id > option").each(function() {
  // if option value in array, add class 
  if (arrayStrs.includes(this.value)) {

    // set matching values to red color 
    $(this).addClass("red");
  }

});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_id">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

(you could also use a Set instead of an array, it would lookup in `O(1)`, and may well be more appropriate because you don't need an ordered collection, just a collection - but that doesn't matter much)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for you time and your help! Your help is much appreciated!